# Android bluetooth DUN

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have been looking around for an option to use BT DUN on android, and have found some apps and responses. However,all the examples I have seen are meant to share the 3g connection on the phone (similar to wifi tethering). I need the opposite, I have a device that provides bt DUN service and I want to use my android phone/tablet to browse the Internet over bt. Nobody seems to do this? Any ideas?
/D